# DAX Query to Count SubAsset For Distinct Unit for table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Question:- Need Count of SubAsset For Distinct Unit Numbers using Dax.

Table:-

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj715.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TrJY.png)

Comment: hello, you can't get any answer by this. please show us what you have tried to do, your column names and data in order, not in comment section. Use code sample in the editor {} to paste your code. (Ctrl + K on windows) or  (command + K  on Mac)

Comment: Added Table Image link.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my updated solution:
First Create a table of records.

```
DEFINE TABLE 
    TblAssets = SELECTCOLUMNS ({
    (1,"A","Act"),
    (2,"B","Act"),
    (1,"A","ACB"),
    (1,"B","ACB"),
    (2,"A","Act")
    },
    "Unit",[Value1],
    "Subasset",[Value2],
    "Activity",[Value3]
    )
```

Resulting Table:

[image: Image_001]

Now lets create a new table and evaluate expression:

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
SUMMARIZE (TblAssets,TblAssets[Unit]),
"Total SubAsset Count per Unit", CALCULATE (COUNT(TblAssets[Subasset])),
"Total SubAsset Count per Unit_",CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT (TblAssets[Subasset]))
)
```

Final_Result:

[image: Image_002]

I hope This solves your problem.

Comment: Count SuBAsset = COUNTX (
    VALUES ( CommonDataObs[subAssetName] ),
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( CommonDataObs[UNIT] ) )
)

Comment: This did not worked because, It is not counting Distinct SubAsset Values

Comment: You put them in the wrong place. It will be like this: Count SuBAsset = COUNTX ( VALUES ( CommonDataObs[UNIT] ), CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( CommonDataObs[subAssetName] ) ) ). Above I also edited.

Comment: But when i give below Formula giving Result as 1 . That is not Expected.                                                Count SuBAsset = COUNTX (
    VALUES ( CommonDataObs[UNIT] ),
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( CommonDataObs[subAssetName] ) )
)

Comment: OKAY. I updated my solution. Can you test it?

Comment: No did not worked

Comment: Hello, I think I solved your problem. Please check my solution above.